# Multiply number within array using an iterator

Tags: ruby

If I would create a new array out of a preexisting one and modify the content using math operators, what would be a good way to do so? When I try with the code below, I receive an error about undefined methods.

```
ary1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
ary2 = ary1.each { |i| 
    ary1[i] = ary1[i] * 10
}
p ary1
p ary2
```

I assume that math operators are not included in the Array class.

Comment: ruby has strange syntax for that, is that a lambda? Or a "proc" as I've heard they're called in ruby? this question likely fits better on StackOverflow as it's technically specific to how to do X in Ruby or moreover "Why doesn't this code work in Ruby"

Comment: `"I assume that math operators are not included in the Array class."`. Array has no need for math operators because it's a container of other objects. The objects themselves *might* have math operators. Array does have "set" operators, but those have a different purpose. Typically we use [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) and its aliases, or [`each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) or [`inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) to manipulate/coerce the contents of an array.

Comment: *, +, - are the math operators for Array.  This is easily checked by using `ri` or checking Array class on http://ruby-doc.org as seen [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html).  The problem was that you were trying to use * on nil not on Array.

Answer (score 8):

You're looking for the `map` function ([docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map)):

```
ary1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
ary2 = ary1.map {|value| value * 10}
```

`map` is generally a great way to produce a new array by transforming a given array. You pass it a block, which is called for each item in the array. The block receives each item - not the index - as an argument, which I've called `value`. The return values of the block are collected into a new array, which is then returned when the `map` function completes.

Comment: The interesting thing is that the word 'collected' was used to describe the behavior for map and not surprisingly collect is an alias for map.

 ary1 = [*(1..5)]
ary2 = ary1.collect {|value| value * 10} (Since the edit got rejected...)